# Font size for app title in Springboard on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, font-size, springboard

What is the font size used for the app title when it is displayed below the icon on an iPad's home screen?

Comment: Is there any way to change the font size of app title/name?

Answer (score 7):

It’s 12pt Helvetica with a 1px black shadow.